# convert values format to be 0.00

Tags: javascript

I have an array in javascript that contain this values

```
  [-6,-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5]
```

but I want to convert this values format to be 0.00 
 I mean the first number -6 should  be -6.00 and so on.Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

use the `toFixed()` function

```
document.write( myarray[0].toFixed(2) ); // Outputs 6.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map every element of array using `toFixed(2)` like bellow

```
var arr = [-6,-5.5,-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5];
arr = arr.map(function (number) {
    return number.toFixed(2);
})

console.log(arr);
```